# jQuery to populate hidden input but retain existing content

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have the following code to populate a hidden input form with the values of all the checkboxes on a page, however I also want to retain the prepopulated values of the checkbox but can't work out how to do this.

Here's my current code, any help would be most appreciated!

```
$(function(){

  function Populate(){
  vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
  }).get().join(', ');
  console.log(vals);
  $('#hidden_form_id').val(vals);
  }

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  Populate()
  }).change();

});
```

Comment: _"however I also want to retain the prepopulated values of the checkbox"_ - Do you mean you want to retain prepopulated values of the hidden input? You won't be able to just append the checked checkbox values to the end of the hidden input's value because this population is done repeatedly each time the checkboxes are changed. Can you clarify the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your statement

Change

```
$('#hidden_form_id').val(vals);
```

To

```
$('#hidden_form_id').val($('#hidden_form_id').val() + vals);
```

You may use `+= operator` to retain existing value using javascript

```
$('#hidden_form_id')[0].value += vals;
```

You code would be

```
 function Populate(){
  vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
  }).get().join(', ');
  console.log(vals);
  $('#hidden_form_id')[0].value += vals;
  }
```

Comment: `$('#hidden_form_id').value += vals;` won't work, it should be `$('#hidden_form_id')[0].value += vals;` (to change the `value` property of the DOM element, not the jQuery object).

Comment: Thanks this is perfect, monday morning brain obviously wasn't working quite right! Thanks again!

Comment: In fact, it seems the script is now duplicating the entire contents of the hidden form field each time a new tickbox is added… hmmmm!

Comment: Keeping the implementation aside tell me what you want to achieve?

Comment: Basically whenever a tickbox is checked I'd like it to add the value to an input. There are multiple checkboxes on the page, i'd like to end up with the following in the input if checkboxes 1, 2, 4, and 9 have been ticked:

checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox4, checkbox9

If the user checks checkbox 3 then unchecks it then checkbox3 shouldn't be in the input

Comment: I think your code was already doin that, one thing which I feel would not be there is change event triggering by  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  Populate()
  }).change();
remove .change()

Comment: I need to be able to have a prefilled value in the input to specify which form this is being sent from, remove doesn't seem to work, neither does .remove() or .empty() hmmmph!

Comment: Managed to use the original code and simply have two inputs, one with the predefined value and another input for the dynamic aspects, thanks for your help with this, much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome, congrats for finding solution. Thanks for patience while reaching the solution.