# Get the values of all checked check boxes and put them in a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I modify this simple check all code to get all the values of the checkboxes after they are checked and then place them into hidden input, each value should be separated with a comma so I can then explode the values in php. The checkboxes are inside table rows

```
//checks all and unchecks all checkboxes based on checkbox in first row of the table.
 $('th input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    var table = $(e.target).parents('table:first');
    $('td input:checkbox', table).attr('checked', e.target.checked);

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this like at this post [jQuery to populate hidden input but retain existing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341313/jquery-to-populate-hidden-input-but-retain-existing-content):

> ```
> function Populate(){
>     vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
>         return this.value;
>     }).get().join(',');
>     console.log(vals);
>     $('#tags').val(vals);
> }
>
> $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
>     Populate()
> }).change();
> ```
>
> and the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YANTh/1/)

Comment: this seems to work well but its putting "on" as the first value in the hidden field

Comment: This seems to be a near-copy of the code from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13341313/237838

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('th input:checkbox').click(function(e) {

   var currentChecked = $('#hiddenInput').val(); 

   if($(this).is(':checked'){
        $('#hiddenInput').val(currentChecked  + ',' + $(this).val());
   }

   //deleting the unchecked checkbox from the list
   else{
       var newValue = currentChecked .replace("," + $(this).val(), "");
   }

});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/mR85S/

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your code already works to check all those checkbox. Basically, you only want to get the values of every checkbox you checked.

```
//checks all and unchecks all checkboxes based on checkbox in first row of the table.
 $('th input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    var table = $(e.target).parents('table:first');
    var checkboxes = $('td input:checkbox', table).attr('checked', e.target.checked);
    var values = '';
    if(e.target.checked) {
       for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
          values += $(checkboxes[i]).val() + ','; // the val method cant retrieve all the values of a set
       }
       values = values.substr(0, values.length - 1);
    }

    //place values in your hidden input

 });
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: this seems to be the closest to what im looking for but it doesn’t quite work. I tired to alert the values when the chack all checkbox is checked but nothing happend it then alterted a blank box on uncheck.

Comment: Note that there was a mistake in the loop condition, but at least getting the values should work if the checkboxes are really checked (that is, if the set is correct). Could you show one of your input? The problem may lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$('th input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
    var table = $(e.target).parents('table:first');
    var vals = [];
    $('td input:checkbox', table).each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', e.target.checked);
        vals.push($(this).attr('checked') ? $(this).val() : '');
    });
    $('#hidden').val(vals.join());
});
```